# Android Fragment RecyclerView Transparent when replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i just want to replace a fragment by using this code:

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.homepage_fragment_menu, fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .commit();
```

the fragment has recyclerview. but when i see the result of fragment, there's no shown of recyclerview. but when i checked in LayoutInspector, it's showed, but invisible like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTpn.png)

---

And here's the code when set the adapter on RecyclerView

```
    bookingHistoryProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    bookingHistoryList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adapterBookingHistoryList = new AdapterBookingHistoryList(this, bookingHistoryListModels);
    bookingHistoryList.setAdapter(adapterBookingHistoryList);
```

Here's the layout code for RecyclerView and Adapter

> XML Fragment Layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".home.bookinghistorypage.BookingHistoryFragment"
    android:gravity="center">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bookingHistory_listBooking"
        android:background="@color/white_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Adapter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/booking_history_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <helper.CustomFontMontserratBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/booking_history_name"

                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <helper.CustomFontMontserratMediumTextView
                android:id="@+id/booking_history_code"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <helper.CustomFontMontserratBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/booking_history_status"
            android:background="@color/lightOrange"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_very_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_tanggal"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <helper.CustomFontMontserratRegularTextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/booking_history_day_booked"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <helper.CustomFontMontserratMediumTextView
                android:id="@+id/booking_history_actual_date"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <helper.CustomFontMontserratMediumTextView
                android:id="@+id/booking_history_time_booked"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"

                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> XML Activity (Parent of Fragment)

```
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:background="@color/black_image_view">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar_title_and_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/homepage_fragment_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            layout="@layout/element_bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/homepage_progressBar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

> AdapterJava

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookingHistoryListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_booking_history,parent,false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new BookingHistoryListViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BookingHistoryListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String data = GetDateUtils.convertEpochToDate(dataList.get(position).getActualDate());
        if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Completed") && dataList.get(position).getFlagRating().equals(false)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), ProfessionalRatingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("professionalId", dataList.get(position).getProfessionalId());
            intent.putExtra("expertiseId", dataList.get(position).getExpertiseId());
            intent.putExtra("professionalName",dataList.get(position).getProfessionalName());
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

        if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("OnProcess")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.on_process));
        }else if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Cancel")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.cancelled));
        }else if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Completed")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.completed));
        }else if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Reserved")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.reserved));
        }else if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Reschedule")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.rescheduled));
        }else if(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus().equals("Confirmed")){
            holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context,R.color.confirmed));
        }

        holder.bookingHistoryName.setText(dataList.get(position).getProfessionalName());
        holder.bookingHistoryStatus.setText(dataList.get(position).getBookingStatus());
        holder.bookingHistoryDayBooked.setText(dataList.get(position).getDayBooked());
        holder.bookingHistoryCode.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"ID: %s",dataList.get(position).getCode()));
        holder.bookingHistoryActualDate.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%s",data));
        holder.bookingHistoryTimeBooked.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"@ %s",dataList.get(position).getTimeBooked()));
        holder.bookingHistoryCardview.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BookingHistoryDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("idProfessionalAdapter", dataList.get(position).getId());
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList!=null ? dataList.size() :0 ;
    }
```

Comment: pics: https://image.ibb.co/m9vG0A/sss.png

Comment: Please edit your question and add your layouts.  If the recycler view is nested within something else at that view is hidden then the recycler view would inherit this and therefore be hidden

Comment: added XML Layout

Comment: Please add your adapter code

Comment: Maybe your view with id `R.id.homepage_fragment_menu` is invisible..?

Comment: I never change prop invisible to it @Aaron

Comment: Could you post the XML layout with id `R.id.homepage_fragment_menu`?

Comment: i've added the XML Activity for fragment @Aaron

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, your XML layout looks fine to me. How do you use `BottomSheetLayout`? It looks suspicious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nesting your fragment view in a [BottomSheetLayout](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/blob/master/bottomsheet/src/main/java/com/flipboard/bottomsheet/BottomSheetLayout.java), and according to the source code, the initial visibility is `View.INVISIBLE`:

```
private void init() {
    // ...
    dimView = new View(getContext()); // Line 150
    dimView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    dimView.setAlpha(0);
    dimView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    // ...
}

public void setContentView(View contentView) {
    super.addView(contentView, -1, generateDefaultLayoutParams());
    super.addView(dimView, -1, generateDefaultLayoutParams()); 
}
```

I'm not familiar with [Flipboard](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) library, but I've got a feeling that you might be using it incorrectly. Maybe try:

```
bottomSheetLayout.showWithSheetView(...)
```

Or please check on their [GitHub](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) for usage.

Answer (score -1):

Your recycler view in xml layout has `android:visibility="gone".  Remove this line or change it to visible.

Comment: If the visibility is `gone` then nothing will be shown in the layout inspector, and secondly the visibility is set as `Visible` in the code

Comment: `bookingHistoryList` is binded to RecyclerView. so first i've set `GONE` but in java code when get the data i change to `VISIBLE`